# Why does a UK-US-UK ticket not cost the same whether booked in the US or UK?

Tags: uk, tickets

Why does a UK-US-UK ticket not cost the same whether booked in the US or UK?

I have both US and UK credit cards, so it doesn't matter to me, but it seems absurd that the LGW-TPA-LGW ticket I just bought for less than $700 on the AA US site would have cost almost £800 on the AA UK site, a difference of almost $300.

Note I am NOT comparing a UK-US-UK trip to a US-UK-US trip. This is for the identical flights on the same days and times from LGW to TPA to LGW.

Comment: You will find the ticket is even cheaper, sometimes up to 20%, when you buy it in EUR, or in Rumanian Lei. I do that regularly.